# Selenium - cannot click on radio button

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python, xpath

I have tried all the possibilities but am unable to click the radio button Yes or No. It would be great if I get some help. I have observed that Need to take this attribute (`<span radiogroup class="slds-radio_faux"></span>`) to click on radio button

```html
<span radiogroup="" class="radio">
<input radiogroup="" type="radio" name="ID_field" id="radio-1-67935789" value="No"> 
<label radiogroup="" for="radio-1-67935789" class="radio__label"> 
<span radiogroup="" class="radio_faux"></span> 
<span radiogroup="" class="slds-form-element__label">No</span> </label> </span>
```

I tried this code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@name = 'id_select' and @value = 'No']/label/span").click()
```

Comment: Try `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name = 'id_select']"`.

Comment: Tried but getting element unable to locate element

Comment: share more of the HTML, because it is hard to tell like this. Copy and paste it, rather than screenshoting.

Comment: <span radiogroup="" class="radio"><input radiogroup="" type="radio" name="ID_field" id="radio-1-67935789" value="No">
<label radiogroup="" for="radio-1-67935789" class="radio__label">
<span radiogroup="" class="radio_faux"></span>
<span radiogroup="" class="slds-form-element__label">No</span>
</label>
</span>

Answer (score 1):

In the screenshot the HTML code isn't right. There are a few issues with the tags in the HTML.

I tried to replicate it on my local HTML file (as shared below) and the click works fine.

My HTML:

```
<html>

<body>
    <span radiogroup class="slds-radio">
        <input radiogroup type="radio" name="id_select" id="radio-1-1-61" value="No">
        <label radiogroup for="radio-1-1-61" class="slda-radio__label">No</label>
    </span>
    <span radiogroup class="slds-radio_faux"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

MY Selenium Code (with Java. You can translate it to Python):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            WebDriver driver;
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//chromedriver");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("file:///home/milin/Downloads/test.html");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name = 'id_select']")).click();

            Thread.sleep(5000);
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

---

**Addendum**:
I also checked this for the HTML code that you have shared in the Comment on the question. This too works fine. Here's my code for it,

HTML:

```
<html>

<body>
    <span radiogroup="" class="radio">
        <input radiogroup="" type="radio" name="ID_field" id="radio-1-67935789" value="No"> 
        <label radiogroup="" for="radio-1-67935789" class="radio__label"> 
            <span radiogroup="" class="radio_faux"></span> 
            <span radiogroup="" class="slds-form-element__label">No</span> 
        </label> 
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Selenium (Java):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            WebDriver driver;
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//chromedriver");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("file:///home/milin/Downloads/test.html");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name = 'ID_field']")).click();

            Thread.sleep(5000);
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Also note;** the name attribute for the `<input>` tag in your screenshot and the HTML code you have shared is different.

In the screenshot it is `name="id_select"` and in the HTML code you shared it is `name="ID_field"`.

---

**Addendum 2**:
Adding alternative code that works after OP commented that there is also radio button with same name.

This time I used the CSS Selector instead of the Xpath to select/click the radio button.

My HTML:

```
<html>

<body>
    <span radiogroup="" class="radio">
        <input radiogroup="" type="radio" name="ID_field" id="radio-1-67935789" value="No"> 
        <label radiogroup="" for="radio-1-67935789" class="radio__label"> 
            <span radiogroup="" class="radio_faux"></span> 
            <span radiogroup="" class="slds-form-element__label">No</span> 
        </label> 
    </span>
    <span radiogroup="" class="radio">
        <input radiogroup="" type="radio" name="ID_field" id="radio-1-67935789" value="Yes"> 
        <label radiogroup="" for="radio-1-67935789" class="radio__label"> 
            <span radiogroup="" class="radio_faux"></span> 
            <span radiogroup="" class="slds-form-element__label">Yes</span> 
        </label> 
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

My Selenium (with Java):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("file:///home/eclipse-workspace/demo/test.html");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='No']")).click();
        
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the above solution, but even for Yes radio button name field is same.
 <input radiogroup="" type="radio" name="ID_field" id="radio-1-67935789" value="Yes">

Comment: In that case, would you please provide the complete HTML with both radio buttons?

Comment: In the meanwhile I have added an alternative that works.